# hosting silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to go live with my silverlight 4 application and host it on the web but some of the web servers i looked at ask if i want the web server to be iis6 or iis7 but im using windows xp and that uses iis5.1 so im a little lost on how to do this.  Also any suggestions on where to host silverlight applications

Answer (score 2):

To host Silverlight, you don't need any specific type or version of a web server.  Whatever they have will be ok.

If you have any server code (asp.net?) then you want to make sure it is IIS, but even then, version 6 or 7 will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Well for simple hosting of a silverlight application you would not have to be concerned about the hosting server, it could even be Apache.

However, if you have server side code which your SL application needs to communicate with, like a WCF or ASMX web service for example, then you would need to consider the hosting envrionment and the installed framework version etc.

Your choice between IIS6 and IIS7 depends on your requirements, if you do not require a specific version the go with what you can get. Personally I prefer IIS 7 so I would focus on that.

Comment: Well i just want to mimic a windows form tcp server and client but instead i want to make a web based application using silverlight.  For the client side it will use silverlight so i can put it on the web, and for the server side it will just be a simple console application.  Do i still have to consider iis or other requirements?

Comment: @user464111, I am not sure I understand, where will the console server be executing? If you do not have any .NET code executing on the WEB server then you can use any web server you want. Also keep in mind that Silverlight has some restrictions on TCP connections depending if the application is trusted or not, here is a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

Comment: thank you for the reply, the server is a console application and just waits for the client to connect.  The client uses silverlight.  Once connected they can interchange data.  Im using my own personal router for this to forward the data to my local computer.  Will that not work with the restriction?

Comment: So if I understand the Console Server application will be running on your local network? If so then yes, you can probably get this to work, either by implemeneting a policy service to grant TCP connection to the SL app, or running the SL app out of browser with elevated trust. Keep in mind that if your SL client is not only going to be used on your local network, but over the internet by users from various locations and networks you will have problems with NAT unless your console server is on a public IP.